# Connecting to Analysis Services from R or Nodejs

Tags: r, node.js, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I am trying to connect Analysis services from either through R or Nodejs.

For R,  I have found the following library:
https://github.com/overcoil/X4R

For Nodejs, I have found the following library:
https://github.com/rpbouman/xmla4js

Analysis Services Server is external. It is not in my local machine. Currently I am able to connect it successfully from Excel using both Windows and basic authentication (username/password).

For accessing it through R or nodejs, in the following link it is said I need to configure http access using IIS. But since it is not local how can I get the
file msmdpump.dll and configure it.

In this link https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/77616-265568694, at the end Sarah Lukens said that I need to follow the steps mentioned in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx

Since I didn't work before in SSAS, I don't have much clarity. Can anyone please guide me in establishing the connection from R or Nodejs to Analysis services. Then I just want to submit the MDX queries and get the result.

thanks,
r karthik.

Comment: Some SSAS users please share your thought on this...How to connect SSAS to any of the programming languages to submit MDX queries..

Comment: I want to know the answer to this too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to connect to your SSAS remotely without IIS. You have to share your msmdpump.dll in order to get access to your SSAS connection for third-party APIs via the xmla interface.